# Amazon SES SMTP Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, sendmail, amazon-ses

I have been trying to set up an email notification for my application using Sendmail along with SES on CentOS 6.5. As per AWS [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html), I have configured sendmail with SES,

The maillog says,

`sendmail[29711]: s2QFCjnu027924: to=<abc@edf.com>, delay=00:52:09, xdelay=00:08:00, mailer=relay, pri=210717, relay=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [107.20.142.169], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

All mails are being added in `mailq`

```
# sendmail -v -q
Running /var/spool/mqueue/s2QFueiS001965 (sequence 1 of 21)
<abc@edf.com> Connecting to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com port 25 via relay.
^C
```

Also, I unable to do telnet to the smtp address,

```
# telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25
Trying 23.21.252.142...
^C
```

But nmap shows port smtp (25) is open and listening,

```
# nmap -p 25 localhost

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-03-26 17:09 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000080s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
25/tcp open  smtp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

netstat output,

```
tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:25   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      29708/sendmail
```

I have tried with EU region `smtp email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` as well, getting the same result.

There is no selinux and iptables running and security group rules are fine with EC2.

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you are sending a test mail as `sudo /usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@example.com to@example.com`, the mail is handed over to the sendmail running on your instance.
- when sendmail tried to deliver the mail to the `SMART_HOST` which is `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, it wasnt able to connect to `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and so the email was placed in the `deferred queue` for retrying later.

So the problem is that your sendmail instance wasnt able to talk to `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

- Is there any network issue in your instance?
- Also the [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html) says that you need to fill  [Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to remove some restrictions on port `25`

Answer (score 25):

I was having trouble with the timeout as well.  I didn't have any vpc subnet routing as thiyagu114 said was his issue, and none of clement's suggestions helped.

Found this on the Amazon info:

> Important Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) throttles email traffic over
>   port 25 by default. To avoid timeouts when sending email through the
>   SMTP endpoint from EC2, use a different port (587 or 2587) or fill out
>   a Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations to remove the throttle.

So switching from port 25 to 587 fixed the timeout issue for me.

Comment: Problem could be the port is not opened in your instance security group outbound rule. Remember to check if you already have port 587 there!

Comment: Had the same problem. Switching to 587 AND opening incoming TCP ports 1024 - 65535 as described on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/smtp-connectivity-timeout-issues-ses/ seemed to fix it.

"Also be sure that network ACL inbound (ingress) rules allow traffic from the SMTP server on TCP ports 1024-65535"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Clement for your help.

I figured it out the issue. it was `vpc subnet routing` problem  with the instance.

Now it works like a charm :-)

Comment: Had a similar issue. All traffic was routed out but the box traffic was routed through didn't have the SMTP ports open.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS SES as relay you should have this configuration:

Edit main.cf:

```
...
relayhost = email-smtp.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
...
```

Edit /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

```
email-smtp.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com:587 SMTP_USERNAME:SMTP_PASSWORD
```

Edit /etc/postfix/transport

```
* smtp:email-smtp.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com:587
```

**Pay attention that you have to specify port on all places, even in transport.**

execute postmap

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/transport
```

restart postfix

```
service postfix restart
```

And it'll work. The rest of configuration you can find at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending to Amazon SES from an Amazon EC2 instance via port 25 and you cannot reach your Amazon SES sending limits or you are receiving time outs then it's probably because Amazon EC2 imposes default sending limits on email sent via port 25 and throttles outbound connections if you attempt to exceed those limits. 
Solutions -
You can connect to Amazon SES using ports 465 or 587, neither of which is throttled.
OR
To remove the limits, submit an Amazon EC2 Request to Remove Port 25 Limitations (https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request).